# DML lock while starting server

Tags: sql, database, oracle

what is DML lock, when it will happen.

while starting the server, i am getting automatically DML lock, i am not able to start the server.

Am unable to find the root cause of it.

Answer (score 3):

> what is DML lock, when it will happen.

As the oracle [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502) states :

> A DML lock is a lock obtained on a table that is undergoing a DML
>   operation (insert, update, delete).

AS for your problem , is there a query running ? or can you know what is happening in your session ?